# Splicing only one element when creating a new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to make it where when a user creates a widget, and then reloads the page (it'll appear because it's saved in localStorage) and then once you create another widget, I want to be able to delete the old widget before the page refreshes but it deletes the widget that the user clicked and the new widget.

Each time a new widget it created, it gets assigned a property name 'id' and the value is determined based on what is already in localStorage and it finds the next available (or not in use) id number. The widgets array also gets sorted from smallest id to largest id before setting it back to localStorage.

I've tried attaching a click listener for the delete button on the widget both when it's created and when the document is loaded. But that wasn't working.

Now i'm thinking I have to call a function with the id as its param to add a click listener to all the widgets that are appended to the document and when a new widget is created.

app.js:

```
function addRemoveListener(id) {
    let storageUi = localStorage.getItem('ui');
    let localUi = JSON.parse(storageUi);
    $(`#widget-${id} > span > .widget-clear`).click(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < localUi.widgets.length; i++) {
            let thisWidget = `#widget-${id}`;

            if (localUi.widgets[i].id == id) {
                localUi.widgets.splice(i, 1)
            }

            $(thisWidget).remove();
            console.log(localUi)
        }

        let newUi = JSON.stringify(localUi);
        localStorage.setItem('ui', newUi);
    })

}
```

widget.js:

```
static appendToDom(ui) {
        let storageUi = localStorage.getItem('ui');
        let localUi = JSON.parse(storageUi);

        for (let i = 0; i < localUi.widgets.length; i++) {
            let widget = localUi.widgets[i];


            let query = () => {
                if (widget.type == 'humidity') {
                    return `${Math.floor(ui.weather.currently.humidity * 100)}`
                } else if (widget.type == 'eye') {
                    return `${Math.floor(ui.weather.currently.visibility)}`
                } else if (widget.type == 'windsock') {
                    return `${Math.floor(ui.weather.currently.windSpeed)}`
                } else if (widget.type == 'pressure') {
                    return `${Math.floor(ui.weather.currently.pressure)}`
                } else if (widget.type == 'uv-index') {
                    return `${ui.weather.currently.uvIndex}`
                }
            }

            $('nav').after(`<div class="widget widget-${widget.size}" id="widget-${widget.id}">
                                <span>
                                    <i class="material-icons widget-clear">clear</i>
                                    <i class="material-icons widget-lock-open">lock_open</i>
                                    <i class="material-icons widget-lock">lock_outline</i>
                                </span>
                                <div class="data-container">
                                    <img src=${widget.image}>
                                    <h1> ${widget.type}: ${query()} ${widget.unit} </h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>`)
            $(`#widget-${widget.id}`).delay(1000 * i).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);

            $(`#widget-${widget.id}`).css({ left: `${widget.left}`, top: `${widget.top}`, 'font-size': `${widget.dimensions[2]}` })
            $(`.widget`).draggable();

            $(`#widget-${widget.id}`).css({ width: `${widget.dimensions[0]}`, height: `${widget.dimensions[1]}` })



            addRemoveListener(i);


}

// this function is called earlier in the script when the user has selected 
// which kind of widget they want 

let makeWidget = () => {
     let newWidget = new Widget(this.size, this.id, this.image, this.type, this.unit, this.dimensions);
                        saveWidget(newWidget);
                        addRemoveListener(this.id)
                    }
```

I have no problems with this until I delete an existing widget after I create a new one, and before refreshing.

Comment: Is your intent to only have 1 widget shown at a time?

Comment: No. They all get shown once the page is refreshed(only if there were any widgets stored in localStorage) They all have a button to delete itself, it's just not working once you try to create a new widget and delete one that's already on the dom. It deletes the one you clicked and all of the current widgets that you just made. But if you create all of them, then refresh and once they are appended to the dom, they work perfectly, just not if you then make another one, and then try to delete one that was already on the screen when the document was first loaded.

Comment: Can you provide the code for saveWidget?

Comment: `let saveWidget = (widget) => {
    let storageUi = localStorage.getItem('ui');
    let localUi = JSON.parse(storageUi);
    localUi.widgets.push(widget)

    console.log(localUi)

    let arr = localUi.widgets;
    let id = localUi.widgets.id;
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.id - b.id;
    });
    
    let newUi = JSON.stringify(localUi);
    localStorage.setItem('ui', newUi);
    console.log(localUi)
   }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You might have a problem with the id that is passed to your addRemoveListener function. It could be passing the same id for any widget so the loop will delete the UI because `thisWidget` is in the for loop. Try adding some console logging.

```
function addRemoveListener(id) {
    let storageUi = localStorage.getItem('ui');
    let localUi = JSON.parse(storageUi);
    $(`#widget-${id} > span > .widget-clear`).click(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < localUi.widgets.length; i++) {
            let thisWidget = `#widget-${id}`;

            if (localUi.widgets[i].id == id) {
                localUi.widgets.splice(i, 1)
            }

            // Move this inside the if statement above.
            $(thisWidget).remove();
            console.log(localUi)
        }

        let newUi = JSON.stringify(localUi);
        localStorage.setItem('ui', newUi);
    })
}
```

or better yet, re-write it to continue if the id doesn't match

```
function addRemoveListener(id) {
    let storageUi = localStorage.getItem('ui');
    let localUi = JSON.parse(storageUi);
    $(`#widget-${id} > span > .widget-clear`).click(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < localUi.widgets.length; i++) {
            let thisWidget = `#widget-${id}`;

            if (localUi.widgets[i].id !== id) {
                continue;
            }

            localUi.widgets.splice(i, 1)
            $(thisWidget).remove();
            console.log(localUi)
        }

        let newUi = JSON.stringify(localUi);
        localStorage.setItem('ui', newUi);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however it didn't seem to work :/ still splices all the created objects(widget) plus the one that you initially wanted to splice(or remove from dom). Works perfectly once i refresh the page and allow all the widgets to be appended , then deleting any of them works fine. I'm not sure why it keeps splicing all of the newly created widgets. Might have to redo from scratch and think of something else. Just super stumped.

Comment: If you created a jsfiddle and shared that it might be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Actually, I figured out the problem. It was all because of whenever you would move the widget on the dom, I save its position on the dom in ui.widgets[whichever one im moving].top/left - and by doing this, i save what's already in localstorage before i splice & save to localstorage. Thanks for the help though! Been working on this dumb bug for days lol. Also, I would have LOVED to put this up to show but i use 2 api keys in the app and I don't know any backend programming yet so i can't hide it.

Comment: @Clayton glad you got it sorted out!